# Why does this Facebook FQL query return empty?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

The following FQL query is returning empty. There's no reason for it not to, as its quite clearly documented as possible in the FQL Documentation itself.

`SELECT eid, uid, rsvp_status FROM event_member WHERE (uid = me() OR uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())) LIMIT 10`

This *should* return the first 10 rows of any events that I, or my friends have been invited to.

If I include a condition for a specific event's ID, then I get the result.

(I am using `FB.Data.query()` to perform the query, in conjunction with `query.wait`.)

Can anyone else replicate this issue, or know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

hi this because of the fact that you have not taken the `user_events` and `friends_events`
You can take permission like this

```
<fb:login-button perms="friends_events,user_events" autologoutlink="true"></fb:login-button>
```

For Further You can read [Manage Permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/).

Comment: Thank you, this definitely got me onto the next stage of debugging. It's still returning empty, but it did request the correct permissions. Thank you